# How to receive quality gate status from SonarQube in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube

For the below pipeline script:

```
   stage('stage1'){

    withSonarQubeEnv(server){
            sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
        }
   }
```

---

`stage1` launches Sonar scan and exit with success state.

`stage2` waits for 30 minutes until sonar scan completes, jenkins is suppose to receive QualityGate status, as per below code.

```
   stage('stage2'){

        timeout(time: 40, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            def qGate = waitForQualityGate()
            if (qGate.status != 'OK') {
                error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qGate.status}"
            }
        }
    }
```

---

We have Sonar server and sonar scanner configured in Jenkins.

Is there additional configuration required to receive quality gate status?

Answer (score 2):

To make it work you need:

1. Sonarqube, use a recent version, LTS 6.7.x or 7.6
2. the Sonarqube Jenkins plugin in version >= 2.6.1
3. the Sonarqube scanner configured in Jenkins
4. the Sonarqube host configured in Jenkins
   to make
    `withSonarQubeEnv(nameofyourconfiguredSonarHost)` work
5. configure a webhook in Sonarqube server:
   goto https://yoursonarhost/admin/webhooks and use that URL
   https://yourjenkins/sonarqube-webhook/ 
   note the trailing '/' !

After that it should work as expected.
In my experience a timeout of 10 mins is sufficient.
Maybe there are additional settings needed, i.e. proxy or firewall to be able
to access Jenkins from Sonarqube - it depends on your network.

Comment: jenkins is able to access SonarQube,  to run sonar scanner.

Comment: @mohet
for the webhook, Sonarqube server must be able to access Jenkins (but it needs no authentication)

Comment: 0

for me, it works even without the trailing '/', so I have configured "https://yourjenkins/sonarqube-webhook" only. Also worth to mention: I kept the field for 'secret' empty in the sonarqube webhook configuration